# Is CommunicationException always/almost always a service issue?

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

Receiving the following exception while communicating with a WCF service.

**CommunicationException: The underlying connection was closed: A connection that was expected to be kept alive was closed by the server.**

The error doesn't not occur with every call and the WCF service is hosted in a pool of several servers. I don't know how many because I don't know the service.

I have located the following article on MSDN that states that many times this error is caused by the service and is not really an exception involving the network transmission of the message.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734691(v=vs.100).aspx

Is there a specific network configuration that would cause this timeout to occur... for instance a connection pool idle timeout of 100 seconds, a server keep-alive of 120 seconds and a network router between the server and the client with an idle timeout of 60 seconds.

The binding configuration that is being used is very simple... BasicHttpBinding configured with the following

valuescloseTimeout="00:01:00"
openTimeout="00:01:00" 
receiveTimeout="00:03:00" 
sendTimeout="00:03:00"
allowCookies="false" 
bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
maxBufferPoolSize="524288" 
maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
messageEncoding="Text" 
textEncoding="utf-8" 
transferMode="Buffered"
useDefaultWebProxy="true"

Comment: It could be any number of things - how are you hosting the service?  How are you using it? If you're hosting it in IIS and not closing the client channel this can cause a problem like this.

Comment: The service is hosted in IIS7